# merging table in Pandas

Tags: python, pandas

I am trying to merge two different tables.

[Table 1 containing NGS FILE chromosome starting & END position and Sequence](https://i.stack.imgur.com/qNTcB.png)

[Table 2 Containing another table which includes Only Chromosome and Pos](https://i.stack.imgur.com/pP2SV.png)

I want to extract Row From Table 1 condition is Pos value (table) is within the range of Pos and PosEnd from table 1.
e.g. Pos 57292 is in Table 2 so I want to Extract value from table 1 where 57292 is between Pos and Pos End in Table 1.

Table 2 size is around 50K and Table 1 Size is 1000K.
Can anyone share the Fastest way?

[Manually checked](https://i.stack.imgur.com/trB7e.png)

Comment: Can you post what you have tried?

Comment: You should post the data. Not images/links

Comment: Given what you've described of the problem, you probably shouldn't do this in Pandas. You should do this in SQL, so you can create a table with a BTREE index, which will allow you to do efficient range queries. If you don't have efficient range queries, you're left with comparing every element in one table to every other element in the other table, which is very slow.

Comment: The data size is very big to post here. Its data from Bio-Informatic, Genome Sequence.

Thank you Nick ODell, If I use DataBase tools I think there will require more dependency while making automation my jobs.
So if I can solve this in Pandas it will be best for me.

Comment: https://drive.google.com/file/d/1JFAieGwd0-ZoiuGEYamapkSPe_dKk7st/view?usp=sharing

Sample File For Chromosome 1 only posted here due to size limitation 
If anyone can help with Pandas Fastest method plz help.

Answer (score 0):

What you are trying to do is merging two dataframes based on a condition (merge rows of `df2` if the position in that dataframe is within the range `Pos` - `Pos_End` in `df1`.).

We can use numpy broadcasting to make this work.

```
# import numpy if you haven't already
import numpy as np
```

**First** we make numpy arrays of the dataframe columns we are going to use for the merge (I named your `table1` and `table2`; `df1` and `df2` in this example).

```
df2_values = df2['Pos'].values
df1_end = df1['Pos_End'].values
df1_start = df1['Pos'].values
```

**Second** find the indices of rows in `df1` and `df2` in which the `Pos` of `df2` is within the range of `Pos` and `Pos_End` in `df1` using numpy broadcasting

```
i, j = np.where((df2_values[:, None] >= df1_start) & (df2_values[:, None] <= df1_end))
```

**Finally** create a new dataframe where with the rows of `df1` and `df2` corresponding to the indices `i` and `j` we found. The column names are just the column names of the original `df1` and `df2` combined.

```
pd.DataFrame(
    np.column_stack([df1.values[j], df2.values[i]]),
    columns=df1.columns.append(df2.columns)
)
```

Comment: Thank you very much. I did the same way but it's time-consuming.